# Como arredondar decimais para cima para obter um inteiro em C#?

Tags: c#, matemática

Tenho a seguinte conta:

```
var NumeroDePaginas = NumeroDeItens / 32;
```

Quando uso o `Math.Round` ele arredonda tanto para cima quanto para baixo. Porém sempre que houver qualquer valor decimal eu desejo retornar um valor inteiro arredondado para cima.

Exemplo: Se `NumeroDeItens / 32` for igual a 1.01, `NumeroDePaginas` será igual a 2.

Como obter esse resultado?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Utilize o Math.Ceiling(), exemplo:

```
var valorArredondado = Math.Ceiling(1.01);
```

Exemplo tirado do MSDN:

```
double[] values = {7.03, 7.64, 0.12, -0.12, -7.1, -7.6};
Console.WriteLine("  Value          Ceiling          Floor\n");
foreach (double value in values)
    Console.WriteLine("{0,7} {1,16} {2,14}", 
                 value, Math.Ceiling(value), Math.Floor(value));

// The example displays the following output to the console: 
//         Value          Ceiling          Floor 
//        
//          7.03                8              7 
//          7.64                8              7 
//          0.12                1              0 
//         -0.12                0             -1 
//          -7.1               -7             -8 
//          -7.6               -7             -8
```

Observação:
Ao utilizar o Math.Ceiling(), caso haja uma divisão de inteiros, pode ocorrer um erro indicando incompatibilidade entre decimal e double, neste caso, deve-se forçar o resultado para ser do tipo double, exemplo:

```
var valorArredondado = Math.Ceiling(3 / 32d);
```

Onde a letra d após o número indica que 32 será do tipo double.

Comment: Obrigado Diego. Vê se pode me ajudar ainda mais... Não estou conseguindo utilizar a expressão Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(3 / 32)). Diz The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Math.Ceiling(decimal)' and 'System.Math.Ceiling(double)'

Comment: Quando você divide dois números inteiros e estes, tem resultado quebrado, automaticamente o resultado é convertido para decimal. Você pode resolver o problema, forçando a conversão ser feita em double, basta usar assim Math.Ceiling(3 / 32d). Este 32d indica que o 32 passa a ser do tipo double, então o resultado também será em double, assim não haverá erro quando chamar o método.

Comment: Era isso mesmo, já ia avisar que consegui, muito obrigado! Acho que essa observação pode ser útil para alguém no futuro. Se quiser complementar a resposta seria legal.

Comment: Tem razão João Paulo, eu adicionei uma observação na resposta. Obrigado.

Answer (score -1):

```
float numero = 5.1f;
float arredondado = (float)Math.Ceiling(numero);
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).